# Using longer key with PKCS#5 derive_key() function for AES256?

Tags: aes, key-size, pbkdf-2

I have code where someone made the key 64 bytes (32*2) and passes to the `derive_key()` function.  It then uses the key created for `aes_encrypt_key256()` which would only use 32 bytes.

Is there any good reason why the code is doing that vs just using a 32 byte key that is passed to `derive_key()` ?

TIA!!

Comment: Not a clear question. What do you expect, run another KDF at that point?

Comment: The question is in terms is it more secure to do it with the 64 bytes to derive_key() vs doing it with just 32 bytes ?

Comment: This is not a programming Q/A site, but I do think that the question is valid. That said please indicate a reference to the language and the actual function being called. It is also very important to include the context, otherwise we may not be able to guess why a KDF is being used in a protocol. I'll close the question until these details are added (by hitting [edit]).